# How to add a Woocommerce Subscription order note programmatically

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

With the below code, I can successfully add a custom order note to a subscription renewal order when the order is completed.

However, I would like to modify this to add the note to the **Subscription Notes** instead of the **Order Notes**. I think Subscription Notes use the same `add_order_note` function as `$subscription->add_order_note` instead of `$order->add_order_note`. But I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to get the $subscription variable to work in the below code.

```
// Add box contents (product excerpt) as order note for subscriptions

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'custom_action_on_completed_customer_email_notification', 10, 4 );
function custom_action_on_completed_customer_email_notification( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {


if( 'customer_completed_renewal_order' == $email->id ){ // for processing order status customer notification…

$product_id = '';

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values) {
    $product_id = $item_values['product_id'];

    break; // (optional) stop loop to first item
}

// The text for the note

$note = get_the_excerpt($product_id);

// Add the note
$order->add_order_note( $note, $is_customer_note = 1 );

// Save the data
$order->save(); 

}

}
```

Do you know what I need to add/change to make this add to a Subscription note instead of order note?

Comment: The method [add_order_note](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#1554-1607) is only wrapper around the [wp_insert_comment function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment) from WordPress. I don`t know the "Subscription note" but if the plugin also stores its notes as comments you could use the funtion *wp_insert_comment*. Look into the comments table and find out under which "comment_type" and "comment_agent" they are stored.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful: [Woocommerce Update Order Notes Date](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309035/woocommerce-update-order-notes-date/309076#309076)